# Extract a particular field from json output using jq

Tags: json, bash, syntax-error, jq

I'm working a bash script to extraxt specific field from json output using `jq`.

```
USERNAME=$(echo "$OUTPUT" | jq -r '.[] | .name')
```

Due to `jq` it always fails with `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 2` error.

My restapi result has the below output.

```
[
  {
    "url": "#/systemadm/groups/uuid-d6e4e05",
    "options": {},
    "group_id": 313,
    "owner": "abc-123-mec",
    "owner_id": "ad1337884",
    "id": "c258d7b330",
    "name": "abc-group"
  },
  {
    "options": {},
    "id": "global%3Regmebers",
    "name": "Udata-123"
  },
  {
    "url": "#/systemadm/groups/uuid-38943000",
    "options": {},
    "group_id": 910,
    "owner": "framework-abcc",
    "owner_id": "78d4472b738bc",
    "id": "38943000057a",
    "name": "def-group"
  },
........................
............................
......................................
```

So what's wrong with this `jq` response of code to get "name" ?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. jq can only work with JSON

Comment: Please don't change your question completely. Now your input actually _is_ valid JSON (if you remove the ",...." part and close the array) and jq shouldn't produce this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jq can only process valid JSON.

If the value of `OUTPUT` is literally `"id": "c258d7b330","name": "abc-group"`, then you could enclose it in curly braces to make it valid JSON. No guarantees though; this depends on the exact format of your input.

```
OUTPUT='"id": "c258d7b330",
"name": "abc-group"'
USERNAME="$(printf '%s\n' "{$OUTPUT}" | jq -r '.name')"
printf '%s\n' "$USERNAME"; // abc-group
```

If it cannot be converted to valid JSON, maybe a simple solution using `grep`+`cut` or `awk` would suffice?

```
OUTPUT='"id": "c258d7b330",
"name": "abc-group"'
USERNAME="$(printf '%s\n' "$OUTPUT" | grep '^"name":' | cut -d'"' -f4)"
```

awk:

```
printf '%s\n' "$OUTPUT" | awk -F'"' '/^"name":/{print $4}'
```

Or even use jq to parse the input as array of strings and then filter for the line in which you are interested:

```
jq -Rr '(select(startswith("\"name\":")) / "\"")[3]'
```

All options are really fragile and I recommend to fix your input to be actual, valid JSON